# Disable Triggers Syntax (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

The  objective of  the exercise is to

-First disable all triggers

-Then insert 5 million rows (Using inserts, SQl*Loader..)

-Then enable triggers again.

I need to say if this is what we need to do or not. My main doubt is that the code that they provide me to enable and disable the trigger is something like this:

```
UPDATE dba_triggers
SET status=’DISABLED’
WHERE owner=’SCOTT’ AND table_name=’DATOS’;

UPDATE dba_triggers
SET status=’ENABLED’
WHERE owner=’SCOTT’ and table_name=’DATOS’;
```

Is it ok to disabling trigger that way ? As far I as know, if we want to do that I need to disable them like:

```
ALTER TRIGGER <trigger_name> DISABLE
```

Comment: the object DBA_TRIGGERS is a data dictionary view, you can use it to check the status of your trigger. You can NOT use it to change the status of the trigger. Best place to start is the official oracle documentation.

Comment: @KoenLostrie So we can't do "update dba_triggers"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only right way is to use [ALTER TRIGGER statement.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-TRIGGER.html#GUID-085BD628-2903-46A3-9850-C0D8ED7F2EEF)